# javascript giving unexpected results

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following javascript:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var fs = require(’fs’);
var outfile = "hello.txt";
var out = "Modify this script to write out something different.\n";
fs.writeFileSync(outfile, out);
console.log("Script: " + __filename + "\nWrote: " + out + "To: " + outfile);
```

on executing the following commands:

```
node test.js
cat hello.txt
```

i get the following output:

```
[object Object]
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I tried your code on Windows, I did not see any issue. I am on node 0.10.x.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.04 , node version v0.10.5. same code working great.

Answer (score 0):

Your getting an object returned as a string. Your going to need find out what properties the object has and return them, or loop through the object and show the properties, or convert it to a string...

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(objToJson));
```

Comment: But according to the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_filename_data_options), it should work with a plain string.

Comment: Whatever "out" is when you run on your set up isn't a plain string.  Have you tried the code you provided?  It works beautifully for me.  What version of node do you have installed on what system?

Comment: @ChrisCM : I am using v0.10.13. I added console.log(out); It prints the string. But not so in the outfile.

Comment: Installed on what system?

Comment: @ChrisCM : ubuntu 12.10